# TI SensorTag CC2650 Handler issue

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, iot

I purchased `TI SensorTag CC2650`, whose HW Rev: `1.3.0` and SW Rev: `1.2.0` to access temperature from it, I use handler `0x24` to write(Enable) and `0x21` to read its value working fine.
Recently we purchased two more `TI SensorTag CC2650`, whose HW Rev: `1.3.2` and SW Rev: `1.2.1` to access temperature from these, TI sensorTags same handler didn't work instead it write(Enable) with `0x27` and read with `0x24`.

And the same thing happening with other sensors too, i.e. Humidity, Gyro etc.
Here is the link of [BLE SensorTag Attribute Table](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf).

Is this attribute table is same for both HW and SW Versions or different?

Any help and guidance will be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to discover services and characteristics with gatttool (or equivalent) ?

Comment: Yes, but they didn't help me.

Comment: You should access attributes via their UUID.  The UUID won't change between revisions.

Comment: @TimTisdall can you please give some sample code to access them via UUID.

Comment: @Irfan you didn't specify what language you're even using...  You could try `gatttool -I` and then type "help".  You want to `connect` to the device you want and read using `char-read-uuid`.  That will fetch based on the UUID and not the handle.  The returned value will contain the handle so you can use it to get the correct handles for writing to the attributes to turn on the sensors.

Comment: I'm using python language on raspberry pi 3's terminal

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem.
I just realized that each sensor tag has same UUID but different handler. You can check the handler for each UUID of the sensor tag by doing this command:

```
gatttool -b <68:C9:0B:06:46:85> --interactive
[68:C9:0B:06:46:85][LE]> char-read-uuid F000AA01-0451-4000-B000-000000000000
handle: 0x0021   value: 00 00 00 00 //this is the result you want
```

Therefore, it is safer to actually write to it using UUID. Hope it helps :)